# Asserting against one of two possible results

Tags: unit-testing

I am trying to write a UnitTest for a test case that has two possible, correct results. Which result is returned depends on the actual implementation, but does not matter to the requirements; either is acceptable.

Two Asserts don't work - one would always fail.

Currently I add the two results to a list, and assert that the calculated result is in that list:

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(result));
```

That works, but in case the test fails it does not give the Expected/Actual output (which is usually very helpful).

Is there a more elegant way to assert against one of two possible expected values?

(I am currently using MSTest, but I am open to hear what other frameworks can offer, or if there is general advice)

Comment: Would `CollectionAssert.Contains(list, result)` be any more elegant?

Comment: @Joseph Kendall 2: a litte. But the error-message it gives when failing is equally flat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assert.IsTrue in both [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.2.7) and [MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms243754%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) have overloads to set the message displayed if the assertion fails. For your case you could edit the assertion like so

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(result), 
    "The list did not contain the value " + result);
```

This message can be as explicit as you would like

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(result), 
    "The list was expected to contain the value " + result
    + Environment.NewLine + "but had the values " + 
    methodToPrintContentsOfList(list));
```

This should help with the vague assertion message problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

use fest assert and:

```
assertThat(calculatedResult).isIn(1, 4, 15, 37);
```

Comment: Nice... but seems like java only at the moment. Thanks anyway!

Comment: why java only? if you don't have such library in your own language, write it. in simplest case it's one method `assertIsIn(actualValue, list...)`. proper design will require probably 2 or 3 classes

Comment: Yes I could do that (and I think there _is_ a point in doing that as an exercise), but using the message feature of the existing asserts is easier/faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
assertIn(a, b)
```

test if a in b
new in  3.1

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html